# Get expiration time of Rails cached item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Somewhere in my app I use

```
Rails.cache.write 'some_key', 'some_value', expires_in: 1.week
```

In another part of my app I want to figure out how much time it is left for that cache item.

How do I do that?

Comment: It is internal for cache store, so you can't. But you can update ttl for some cache stores(for example `touch` for memcached)

Comment: I use Redis. Is there a way to `touch` cache item in there?

Comment: In redis it is called `expire` (here are examples if you use `redis-rb` adapter https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/wiki/Redis-rb-Overview)

Comment: There is an issue open to make `#read_entry` a public method. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45313

Answer (score 15):

This is not a *legal* way, but it works:

```
expires_at = Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, 'my_key', {})&.expires_at
expires_at - Time.now.to_f if expires_at
```

`read_entry` is protected method that is used by [fetch](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L324), [read](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L358), [exists?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L501) and other methods under the hood, that's why we use `send`.

It may return `nil` if there is no entry at all, so use `try` with Rails, or `&.` for safe navigation, or `.tap{ |e| e.expires_at unless e.nil? }` for old rubies.

As a result you will get something like `1587122943.7092931`. That's why you need `Time.now.to_f`. With Rails you can use `Time.current.to_f` as well.

Comment: Have a look at these 2 methods https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L782-L788

Comment: `Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, key).instance_variable_get(:@expires_in)` might also work, `@expires_in` holds the expiration value so it can be compared without further operations.

Comment: @SebastianPalma but that won't give you what the original question was, which is `how much time it is left`.

Comment: Just as a follow-up to @NickRoz, here's what `expires_at` looks like: `@expires_in ? @created_at + @expires_in : nil`. So it stores both the `created_at` and `expires_in` values in the cache, which it uses to determine if the cache entry is expired or not. Neat!

Comment: NOTE: You need to normalize the key now so see this answer for how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69159992/293280

Answer (score 5):

Wow. I just came here looking for this. What a shame the answer is no.

My solution, then, which I'm not a fan of, is to cache the expiration as well.

```
Rails.cache.write 'some_key', ['some_value', 1.week.from_now], expires_in: 1.week
```

I suppose it's not the end of the world, except that you have to remember it was stored as an array.

Alternatively you could abstract the functionality a little with a cacheable module. Then you don't have to "remember" anything.

Comment: You may not be a fan, but IMO this is a great solution. Since that info is data you care about, it makes sense for you to explicitly manage that. Granted, this would be a reasonable thing for the library to expose, but perhaps there are good reasons it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me to get the remaining TTL of a specific cache key (in a Redis cache store):

```
Rails.cache.redis.ttl("#{Rails.cache.options[:namespace]}:#{my_key}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Update, you might have to normalize key first

```rb
normalized_key = Rails.cache.send(:normalize_key, key, {})
expires_at = Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, normalized_key, {}).expires_at
expires_at - Time.now.to_f if expires_at
```

Comment: And then how do I convert it to see the hour and minutes when it is going to expire?

Answer (score 0):

In RSpec, you would be travel to any time, so:

```
context 'If key expires' do
  let(:cache) { ::ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new(expires_in: 10.seconds) }

  before { cache.write(key, value) }

  it 'After time, key must expire' do
    travel_to Time.current 11.seconds do
      expect(cache.read(key, value)).to be_blank
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer - this is the most obvious way, and you don't need to access internals or undocumented behavior.